# Temporary files of Chrome in OS X Yosemite

Tags: google-chrome, osx-yosemite, temporary-files

I don't find any "Google" file at "Library/Caches", nor I found "Chrome" file at "ApplicationSupport/Google", so the given answers for finding temporary files don't work for me.

Does anybody know of any other way?

Comment: This appears to be a partial question. Are you able to [edit] your question to either explain in more detail what you are trying to achieve or include a link to the other question for some context. Please see [ask] and take our [tour].

Answer (score 0):

I know that the short term files are stored in /private/var/folders/ but to double check, try running (if you haven't yet)

```
sudo fs_usage -f pathname Google\ Chrome
```

Hope this helps!